# Using Github Actions to Generate a CSV File and Send the CSV File to Box

Tags: csv, github, export, github-actions, box

My team is trying to automate schedule reports. We use R or Python to get data from a database and generate csv files or pdfs. We want to put those files in a box folder (box is like One Drive or Google Drive for those unfamiliar). I know I can use github actions to run a the R or Python scripts at a certain time, but how do I get it to export to particular box folder?
Literally anything you can give me would be appreciated. Even if it was just the words I need to google.

Comment: Try the box API docs: https://developer.box.com/reference/